# react rendering component dynamically inside a loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

trying to render component dinamically in a loop but it is giving me this error however directly sending the data in props working fine
 `ongoingAssesements = assesmentData.filter((item) => item.assesmentStatus == "ongoing") newAssesements = assesmentData.filter((item) => item.assesmentStatus == "new") console.log(newAssesements) completedAssesements = assesmentData.filter((item) => item.assesmentStatus == "completed")`
below code is working fine

```
 <Assessments data={assesmentData[2]} />
```

but while looping it is giving error

```
{(completedAssesements && completedAssesements.length > 0) &&
            completedAssesements.map((item) =>
             <Assessments data={item} />
             
            )

 **error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setExtraStackFrame') **
```

Comment: What is setExtraStackFrame in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key is missing.

Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity - From React Docs
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

```
{(completedAssesements && completedAssesements.length > 0) &&
            completedAssesements.map((index, item) =>
             <Assessments key={index} data={item} />
             
)}
```

You can refer to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20359

Comment: thank you, i am learning react  this helped me a lot

Comment: Yes. It seems that now React 18 is throwing  a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setExtraStackFrame')` if you forget to add a `key` while looping through an array with `map`. The error used to be more descriptive, something like `every prop needs a key` in earlier versions of React

Comment: In map function It is probably: item, index